# Can anybody solve this programming challenge?

Tags: go

Can anybody solve the following question using the programming language Go?

> James got hold of a love letter that his friend Harry has written for
>   his girlfriend. Being the prankster that James is, he decides to
>   meddle with it. He changes all the words in the letter into
>   palindromes.
>
> While modifying the letters of the word, he follows 2 rules:
>
> 1. He always reduces the value of a letter, e.g. he changes 'd' to
>      'c', but he does not change 'c' to 'd'.
> 2. If he has to repeatedly
>      reduce the value of a letter, he can do it until the letter becomes
>      'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be
>      changed.
>
> Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single
>   operation. Find the minimum number of operations he carries out to
>   convert a given string into a palindrome.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer T, i.e., the number
>   of test cases.  The next T lines will contain a string each.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> A single line containing the number of minimum
>   operations corresponding to each test case.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 10 1 ≤ length of string ≤ 104  All characters are
>   lower cased.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> #00 3 abc abcba abcd
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> #00 2 0 4
>
> #### Explanation
>
> For the first test case, ab*c* -> ab*b* -> ab*a*.  For the
>   second test case, abcba is a palindromic string.  For the third test
>   case, abc*d* -> abc*c* -> abc*b* -> abc*a* = ab*c*a -> ab*b*a.

The puzzle is taken from HackerRank.com I am a golang newbie and couldn't solve the puzzle using the language.

Comment: Belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hint: characters are represented as numbers. What's the distance between any two numbers?

Comment: The constraint should be more precise: All characters are lower case ASCII letters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly special about a solution in the Go programming language. For example,

```
// The Love-Letter Mystery
// https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// palindrome returns the minimum number of operations carried out
// to convert a word into a palindrome.
// A word is a set of lower-case ASCII letters.
func palindrome(word string) (ops int) {
    for i, j := 0, len(word)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        n := int(word[i]) - int(word[j])
        if n < 0 {
            n = -n
        }
        ops += n
    }
    return ops
}

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if scanner.Scan() {
        t, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
            t = 0
        }
        for ; t > 0 && scanner.Scan(); t-- {
            fmt.Println(palindrome(scanner.Text()))
        }
        if t > 0 {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", io.ErrUnexpectedEOF)
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
    }
}
```

Input:

```
3
abc
abcba
abcd
```

Output:

```
2
0
4
```

Input:

```
3
cba
cbabc
dcba
```

Output:

```
2
0
4
```